# PHP string : remove last item after slash

Tags: php, string, substring

Is there a better way of removing the substring after the last slash (including the slash)?:

```
$string = '/me/you/them/him';

echo substr($string, 0, -(strlen(basename($string)) + 1));
```

Comment: How do you define a _better_ way?

Comment: [`dirname`](http://php.net/dirname) would work for that exact sample.

Comment: I would explode the string by the / and just re-build the string without the last one.

Comment: Perhaps more `efficient` - is the a function that can do similar thing without calling so many separate functions?

Comment: For more general case (any separator), `implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $string), 0, -1)`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid explode and implode - the answer below is exactly what I was after - a more simpler way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about [`dirname`](http://php.net/dirname) function ?

```
$output = dirname($string);
```

Output:

```
string '/me/you/them' (length=12)
```

Comment: still 6min left before I can

Answer (score 1):

As it is not clear what **better way** means to you, here is one alternative method that came to my mind:

```
$str = '/me/you/them/him';

// Split $str on '/' char into an array
$pieces = explode('/', $str);
// Glue the pieces back together, excluding the last item
$str = implode('/', array_slice($pieces, 0, -1));

echo $str; // '/me/you/them'
```